# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException while copying file to network server

Tags: java, file, copy, network-share

I am running a application (in windows 2012 R2 server), which copies the file to a network path but getting the below exception

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\test\files\test.zip -> \\networkserver\d$\test.zip
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:202)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:279)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1294)
    at com.tesco.deployer.service.FileService.copyFileToRemote(FileService.java:36)
```

Strange part is that I am able to access the path `\\networkserver\d$` manually from the windows server through file explore and can't see any access issue.

```
public void copyFileToRemote(String filepath, String filename, String networkserver) throws IOException {
        Path remotePath = Path.of("\\\\networkserver\\d$\\",filename);
        Files.copy(Path.of(filepath,filename),remotePath);
        logger.info("{} is successfully transferred to store {}",filename,networkserver);
    }
```

Could anyone suggest if I am missing anything.

Regards,

Comment: Does the user you run your application with have access?

Comment: Are you aware that when you type `\\networkserver\d$` into the Explorer’s address box, the Explorer might perform a login using previously stored credentials?

Comment: @Holger when I am manually running standalon java file, that's also successfully copying the file. I haven't passed any credential in the standalone code.

Comment: You have to make clear how “manually running standalone java file” differs from the scenario where it fails. Maybe, it leads to the answer already. The service runs as a different user, maybe?

Comment: Thanks @Holger I set the specific og on account on the service instead of default "Local System" and was able to transfer the file successfully. You can post it in answer and I will mark it accepted.